# Sum across selected columns in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

```
x <- list(a = matrix(c(rep(1, times = 8), 9:16), nc = 4), b = matrix(1, nc = 4, nr = 4))
```

My data share the 1st and 2nd column while the 3rd and 4th column is different

If I want to add the corresponding elements of each list

```
Reduce("+",x)
```

How can I only add the 3rd and 4th column while keeping the 1st and 2nd column intact?

Comment: `cbind(x[[1]][,c(1,2)], Reduce("+", lapply(x, function(p) p[,3:4])))`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not select the 3rd and 4th column before adding?

```
cbind(x[[0]][,1:2], Reduce("+", lapply(x, function(mat) mat[, 3:4])))
```